# Scheduled batch script backup folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, scheduler

Hello not sure where I should place this question but;

I want to run a batch script on a windows machine every night around midnight.

All I want it to do is back up all files and folders on a network drive and copy this to a hard drive on the computer running the batch script. The only thing unsual I want it do is exclude copyying a folder called trashbox

```
Local Computer
C:\BACKUP\

Network Drive
Z:\FILES\*
exclude Z:\FILES\trashbox
```

So it needs to;

1. Remove previous days backup
2. Start at midnight
3. Backup all files and folders on Z:\FILES*
4. Exclude Z:\FILES\trashbox* from copying

Any ideas would be most appreciated!!

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler + xcopy / robocopy. What does this have to do with MS DOS?

Comment: is xcopy not just for windows server? Im running windows 7

Comment: It's on 7 too, so you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this: it will create a `mirror backup` and `delete files that aren't needed` but `keep files that already exist`, and only copy the different files.

```
robocopy "Z:\FILES" "C:\BACKUP" /mir /xd "trashbox"
```

Comment: Thanks for this foxidrive, how would you exclude multiple folders? 
robocopy "Z:\FILES" "C:\BACKUP" /mir /xd "trashbox" /xd "anotherdir"

Comment: Yes, in the way you have shown.  Add `/xd "another folder"`

Answer (score 0):

Create new batch file using below code. It will first remove the previous directory and create new one after that copy all content to new dir from network drive.

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Backup"
TIMEOUT 5
mkdir "C:\Backup"
copy /y "Z:\Networkfolder" "C:\Backup"
TIMEOUT 5
rmdir /s /q "C:\Backup\trashbox"
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for this but how can i exclude the trashbox folder from copying?

Comment: I have updated the answer. The best way is to remove trashbox folder from your local drive. It will be more easier and simpler way.

Comment: The files transferring are quite large so thats why I wanted to exclue the trashbox as it may take a few more hours with this attached to the copying process

Comment: For that you can use Robocopy which is compatible to Windows 7 and will provide the option to exclude any folder or file.